# How can i start logging in already opened connection in teraterm from another application(c#)

Tags: teraterm

I am writing an application for teraterm using c# and i have a problem with logging. I have already oppened connection and read the data,now i need to start logging from my application. Every script i tried is opening a new window of teraterm with new connection. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I am using ttl script

logopen filename 0 0 1 1 1 1
logclose

When i run this macro directly from teraterm it works, but when i run it from my application or cmd it just opens a new window